# TypeError: SSLError(CertificateError("hostname 'abc.com' doesn't match 'def.com'",)

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ssl, django, node.js

currently I am using a `django` backend which makes another `post request` to a `expressjs` backend. I have tested in development server and local machine, worked the `request` was made perfectly.  So I push it to production which does not work at all.

then I see there's this error `TypeError: SSLError(CertificateError("hostname 's.com' doesn't match 'f.com'",)` which is weird.  `f.com` is in the same `server instance` in `s.com` but their server block config is separated though.

Currently using `let's encrypt certbot` for these two domains.
Why would this be happening and anyhow I can track down more how is this happening?

Thanks in advance for any help.

in my `/etc/nginx/sites-available` I have a file for `s.com` and `f.com`

as for `f.com` here is my config

```
server {
    client_max_body_size 100M;
    listen 80;
    server_name f.com;

location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3005;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/f.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/f.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


if ($scheme != "https") {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot

}
```

as for `s.com` here is my config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name s.com;

location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3006;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    # deny all;
}

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/s.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/s.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

# Redirect non-https traffic to https
if ($scheme != "https") {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot

}
```

Comment: So what is the nginx configuration?

Comment: @MichaelHampton added configuration

Comment: are you sure that both configuration file is loaded in nginx configuration? please check it with 'nginx -T'

Comment: @IlhamSulaksono checked, it's loaded I am able to see it when I check with `nginx -T`

Comment: @Dora please make sure that the certificate really belongs to that domain. Maybe you can check it with 'openssl x509 -in fullchain.pem -text -noout'

Comment: @IlhamSulaksono I ran the command you gave me  `sudo openssl x509 -in /etc/letsencrypt/live/s.com/fullchain.pem -text -noout` I can see `Subject: CN=s.com` and `X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: s.com` I did the same check with `f.com` which gives me the result of `f.com` I believe that means certificate belongs to the domain right?